# Why do C# multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have just noticed that a multidimensional array in C# does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, while it does implement `IEnumerable`. For single-dimensional arrays, both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` are implemented.

Why this difference? If a multi-dimensional array is `IEnumerable`, surely it should also implement the generic version? I noticed this because I tried to use an extension method on a multidimensional array, which fails unless you use `Cast<T>` or similar; so I can definitely see the an argument for making multidimensional arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

To clarify my question in code, I would expect the following code to print `true` four times, while it actually prints `true`, `false`, `true`, `true`:

```
int[] singleDimensionArray = new int[10];
int[,] multiDimensional = new int[10, 10];

Debug.WriteLine(singleDimensionArray is IEnumerable<int>);
Debug.WriteLine(multiDimensional is IEnumerable<int>);
Debug.WriteLine(singleDimensionArray is IEnumerable);
Debug.WriteLine(multiDimensional is IEnumerable);
```

Comment: Also ugly: `multiDimensional` is implicitly convertible to the **non-generic** type `System.Collections.IList` (simply because `System.Array` implements that interface). So you could say `System.Collections.IList mdCast = multiDimensional;`. Then using the one-parameter indexer on `mdCast` will fail only at runtime. See [doc on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494734.aspx). Note the exception type, `ArgumentException`. Really ugly.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The CLR has two different kinds of arrays: *vectors* which are guaranteed to be one-dimensional with a lower bound of 0, and more general arrays which can have non-zero bounds and a rank other than 0.

From section 8.9.1 of the CLI spec:

> Additionally, a created vector with
>   element type T, implements the
>   interface
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<U>`
>   (§8.7), where U := T.

I have to say it seems pretty weird to me. Given that it already implements `IEnumerable` I don't see why it shouldn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. It wouldn't make as much sense to implement `IList<T>`, but the simple generic interface would be fine.

If you want this, you could either call `Cast<T>` (if you're using .NET 3.5) or write your own method to iterate through the array. To avoid casting you'd have to write your own method which found the lower/upper bounds of each dimension, and fetched things that way. Not terribly pleasant.

Comment: Also, the C# Language Specification (version 4.0) mentions in paragraph 6.1.6 **only** the conversion of a single-dimensional array to `IList<>` and its base interfaces. But it's a shame that a `T[,]` is not an `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 18):

There is a workaround: you can convert any multidimensional array to an IEnumerable

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this Array target)
    {
        foreach (var item in target)
            yield return (T)item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! I had to explicitly specify the generic type though, so usage becomes: myArray.ToEnumerable<myType>()

Comment: This is the same as `IEnumerable.Cast<T>`.

Comment: @Markus Brilliant, this should be the accepted answer. As an aside, if the array can contain empty values it becomes Matrix.Cast(Of T).Where(Function(x) x IsNot Nothing)

Comment: @smirkingman or [`IEnumerable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913)

Comment: This accesses the array through `IEnumerator` which causes boxing, as @SergeyTeplyakov said in his answer. Boxing doesn't happen if the array is explicitly typed (`T[,]`, `T[,,]`, etc.).

Answer (score 14):

Zero bound single dimensional arrays implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, but multi-dimensional arrays, unfortunately, implements only `IEnumerable`. The "workaround" by @Jader Dias indeed converts a multidimensional array to `IEnumerable<T>` but with a huge cost: every element of an array will be boxed.

Here is a version that won't cause boxing for every element:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T[,] target)
    {
        foreach (var item in target)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d be interested in an explanation about how this avoids boxing, given the foreach statement typically just calls `GetEnumerator()` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Jagged arrays don't support `IEnumerable<int>` either, because multidimensional structures aren't really an array of a type, they are an array of an array of a type:

```
int[] singleDimensionArray = new int[10];
int[][] multiJagged = new int[10][];

Debug.WriteLine(singleDimensionArray is IEnumerable<int>);
Debug.WriteLine(multiJagged is IEnumerable<int[]>);
Debug.WriteLine(singleDimensionArray is IEnumerable);
Debug.WriteLine(multiJagged is IEnumerable);
```

Prints true, true, true, true.

**Note**: `int[,]` isn't an `IEnumerable<int[]>`, that's for the reasons specified in the other answer, namely there's no generic way to know which dimension to iterate over. With jagged arrays, there isn't as much room for interpretation because the syntax is pretty clear about it being an array of arrays.

Comment: Recursion isn't under discussion.

Comment: @recursive: cheers, fixed. Just a case of mixing up my terminology.

Comment: He does not talk about jagged arrays, he talked about a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Think inversely. The 2d array already exists. Just enumerate it. Create a 2d array with score and place of an initial array or marks, including duplicate values.

```
int[] secondmarks = {20, 15, 31, 34, 35, 50, 40, 90, 99, 100, 20};

IEnumerable<int> finallist = secondmarks.OrderByDescending(c => c);

int[,] orderedMarks = new int[2, finallist.Count()];

Enumerable.Range(0, finallist.Count()).ToList().ForEach(k => {orderedMarks[0, k] = (int) finallist.Skip(k).Take(1).Average();
orderedMarks[1, k] = k + 1;}); 

Enumerable.Range(0, finallist.Count()).Select(m => new {Score = orderedMarks[0, m], Place = orderedMarks[1, m]}).Dump();
```

Results:

```
Score Place

100     1
99      2 
90      3 
50      4 
40      5 
35      6    
34      7    
31      8    
20      9     
20     10 
15     11
```