# how can I convert Image to 2 dimensional Array in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have image in C# and I created array of that **but**
 for filtering and mask the picture I need **2 dimensional Array** of image
thank for your help!

Comment: Can you show how you have created a mono dimensional array from your image? Please tell us more also about what image format you are using.

Comment: Do the inverse of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638701/how-to-create-an-image-from-a-2-dimensional-byte-array

Answer (score 1):

Creating a 2d array from your image, or from your 1d array, is pretty straightforward. Here is the way to do it from your 1d array, although this can be easily translated directly to your image code:

`int[][] To2dArray(int[] source, int width) 
{
    int height = source.Length / width;
    int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = source[i * width + j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}`