# Can not cast IEnumerable<int> from LINQ to List<int> with .ToList()?

Tags: c#, linq

After reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/902123 I wanted to check out how LINQ would work on multi-dimensional lists, so here is some test code that I just can not get right.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Two dimensional list of ints
        var arr = new List<List<int>>();
        var rand = new Random();

        // fill the array with random values, this works fine.
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            arr.Add(new List<int>());
            for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
            {
                arr[i].Add( rand.Next(1, 21) );
            }
        }

        var q = from int e in arr select e;
        List<int> lst = q.ToList();  // This fails with InvalidCastException

        // here I would like to pretend that the list is one dimensional
        foreach (int i in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the list should look like it has only one dimension, after I cast the query back to List< int >.

What might be the cause of the problem:

Visual studio tells me that 'q' has type

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator< int, int >}
```

Whereas the answer I linked to at the top of this question states that 'q' should have type

```
IEnumerable< int >
```

**Question 1**: Why is the exception thrown?

**Question 2**: How can I convert multi-dim list to one dimensional list with LINQ?

Thank you.

Comment: for the first one, there's no implicit cast available from IEnumerable<T> to List<T>.And your LINQ query seems wrong.It returns **Specified cast is not valid**

Comment: Use `SelectMany<>` to flatten the list. E.g: `List<int> lst = arr.SelectMany(it=>it).ToList();` and no need for: `var q = from int e in arr select e;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

I think like this:

```
var q = from int e in arr select e;
```

This is your code where your have wroten a query which will be executed later.

```
List<int> lst = q.ToList();
```

In this code you are calling your **query to execute** and then make `.ToList()`.

Here you have declared a statement like this:

```
var arr = new List<List<int>>();
```

but in the query your trying to cast its content which is as `List<int>` to `int`,so this is why your are getting exception `InvalidCastException`.
Your incorrect code is in

```
 var q = from int e in arr select e;
```

Here `e` is a List a your are trying to cast it to `int` and so you have your exception

**Answer 2:**

Change your code like this:

```
var q = from e in arr 
        from i in e select i;
List<int> lst = q.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

**1. Why is the exception thrown?**

```
    from e in arr select e;
```

instead of

```
    from int e in arr select e;
```

It was throwing exception because you were attempting to cast `List<int>` to `int`. More ever linq is smart enough to identify the type of variable do not specify it explicitly is recommended practices.

**2. How can I convert multi-dim list to one dimensional list with LINQ?**

make a use of selectMany method for above case.

```
    List<int> lst = q.SelectMany(d => d).ToList();
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3j2nsC) is .net fiddle for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the SelectMany which seems more appropriate in production (so +1), but I will choose @Suren answer, because he provided the LINQ version which is what interested me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code as shown below and check if that work as you expected:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
     arr.Add(new List<int>());
     for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
     {
          arr[i].Add( rand.Next(1, 21) );
     }
}

//var q = from int e in arr select e; Remove this line
List<int> lst = arr.SelectMany(it=>it).ToList(); //This will flatten the result set
```

Answer (score 0):

In you query `from int e in arr select e` You are trying to get int value from `arg` while each value of your `arg` is `List<int>`. Thats why you get `InvalidCastException` because it can not cast `List<int>` to `int`. If you want to get value from internal `List<int>` you can use query `arg.Select(list => list).Select(val => val)`