# Convert dictionary of any type to IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I've written some code to output any `IEnumerable` collection to a file, but can't pass dictionaries to it. I'm now trying to convert the dictionary (which might be `int`, `int` or `int`, `string` or any other combination) into an array so I can do this. The code below indicates an error when I try to pass it to the method requiring the `IEnumerable`.

Generics are something I haven't done much with so perhaps I've done something wrong with those.

```
public static bool DictionaryToFile<T, U>(Dictionary<T, U> TheDictionary, string FilePath)
{
    long count = 0;
    string[,] myArray = new string[2,TheDictionary.Count];
    foreach (var current in TheDictionary)
    {
        myArray[0, count] = current.Key.ToString();
        myArray[1, count] = current.Value.ToString();
    }

    // error appears here
    TypedListToFile<string[,]>(myArray, FilePath);

    return true;
}
```

The other one I'm calling:

```
public static bool TypedListToFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> TypedList, string FilePath)
```

Comment: What's the problem to pass dictionary to this method? Dictionary<T,U> class implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,U> >

Comment: Thanks Makkam - I kind of thought the same (though had tried Dictionary not KeyValuePair).  You are right!  If you'd like to put this as an answer I'll tick it off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do: when you read: [Why do C# Multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet) You'll see that a multidimensional array doesn't implement IEnumerable, so you have to convert it first. Yet, your code doesn't make sense. I assume you need to increment count in your loop?

Now as for solutions: you can simulate VB behaviour which automatically **converts** multi-dimensional arrays into enumerables by applying a linq query over it. like:

```
var arrayEnumerable = from entry in myArray select entry;
// and some proof that this works:
foreach (string entry in arrayEnumerable)
{
    // this will succesfully loop your array from left to right and top to bottom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypedListToFile<string[,]>(myArray, FilePath);
```

The type of myArray is not `IEnumerable<string[,]>`, so myArray can't be the first parameter to this method.

Comment: Yep that's an issue.  Makkam has correctly pointed out that if I used KeyValuePair I can actually use the dictionary directly with my original method which is great.  Thanks for your answer David.