# Cannot convert from myclass[,] to IEnumerable<myclass>

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public static HashSet<myclass> mymethod(int somenum)
{
    myclass[,] myarray = new myclass[somenum, somenum];                
    // process myarray here
    return new HashSet<myclass>(myarray);
}
```

but on the last line, I get two errors:

> Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet.HashSet(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'myclass[*,*]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), arrays implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`. So why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? A `HashSet` is one-dimensional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C# Multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: alright... thanks anyway

Comment: @minitech kindly post it as an answer so that it helps future visitors..

Comment: @testgo post the answer as an answer and accept it. Visit this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments

Comment: ??? i posted an answer but it got  converted to a comment. "trivial answer converted to comment" it says. howto fix this?

Comment: @minitech I just meant if you could answer it rather than a comment, then it would help future visitors..

Comment: @nawfal: No, asking "What are you expecting to do" is not an answer.

Comment: @minitech The class `HashSet<>` has a public constructor that takes a generic `IEnumerable<>` as its sole argument. Unfortunately, the multi-dimensional array `myarray` is only a non-generic `IEnumerable`. To fix the error, using Linq, one can say `new HashSet<myclass>(myarray.Cast<myclass>())`.

Comment: I posted a "Community Content" comment on the MSDN page linked in the question, to correct their error. My comment will probably appear soon. But it's stil a shame that a `T[,]` is not an `IEnumerable<T>`.