# Constructing C# Lists from that what is enumerable

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections, ienumerable

```
var t = new List<byte?[,]>();
var t2 = new byte?[4, 4][];

var r = new List<byte?[,]>(t);
var r2 = new List<byte?[,]>(t2); // error
```

I thought C# lists and arrays are both Enumerable, and that lists can be constructed from an enumerable object to create a copy of the collection.

Whats wrong with the last line from the example above?

Compile error: The best overloaded method match for 'List.List(IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: The List and Array must have elements of the same type. You try to initialize a list of byte arrays with the bytes from an array of bytes.

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't compile because it's ambiguous. How to lay elements inside the list? By row or by column?

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet

Comment: @lukas that doesn't make sense. It's an array of 2D arrays that he's trying to assign to a list of 2D arrays.

Comment: @AndreiSchneider I'm not buying that. That asks why multi-dimensional arrays don't impelement `IEnumerable<T>`. He has an array *of* 2D arrays.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  ahh I didn't notice the [];

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: No, he actually has a 2D array of 1D arrays. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx

Comment: @Ani, Ah, wow you are correct. I guess I have never used the array of arrays syntax before, and it seems backwards to me. In that case Andrei is also correct.

Comment: @Ani also, thank you for that link. Much better than the MSDN documentation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `t2` should be an array of 2D arrays (list assignment suggests so) then the declaration of `t2` is wrong. If think you are after:

```
var t = new List<int[,]>();
var t2 = new int[10][,];
for (int i = 0; i < t2.Length; ++i)
{
    t2[i] = new int[4, 4];
}

var r = new List<int[,]>(t);
var r2 = new List<int[,]>(t2); // no error!
```

Comment: It might be nice if you also reference the blog post from Eric Lippert on "Arrays of Arrays" that Ani posted in the comments.

Comment: I haven't really used it as a reference since this is quite obvious, but for future reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays.aspx

Comment: It's not that obvious, the article opens with the idea that most people would slip up in the same way I did.

Answer (score 0):

> Whats wrong with the last line from the example above?

The line throws error because t2 is `new byte?[4, 4]` a array of 2d array, well as r2 is a `List of byte?[,]` 2d array

```
var r2 = new List<byte?[,]>(t2); // error
```

so solution will be do pass a `list of byte?[,]` in it like this

```
var r2 = new List<byte?[,]>(new List<byte?[,]>());
```

Also t is the matching 2d array in a list that can be passed in r2

```
var r2 = new List<byte?[,]>(t);
```

Comment: t is a (list) of ((2d array) of (byte?)). t2 is an (array) of ((2d array) of (byte?)).

Comment: @alan2here yes your right did not notice the [] at the end. I was in a hurry to post answer first. thank you ill correct my answer now

Comment: @alan2here See the question comments. You are incorrect. `t2` is a (2d array) of (array of (byte?)). And that's why the conversion to `IEnumerable` fails.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. It does seem to compile now. I've possibly been reading the line the wrong way round.

Comment: @alan2here I don't understand why I got -1 for I gave the solution to it