# Is there a c# library that provides array manipulation like numpy

Tags: c#, arrays, numpy

I am starting to use the Numpy and really like it's array handling capabilities. Is there some library that I can use in C# that provides similar capabilities with arrays.  The features I would like most are:

- Creating one array from another
- Easy/trival iteration of arrays of n dimension
- Slicing of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a library. I think LINQ does all you mention quite well.

## Creating one array from another

```
int[,] parts = new int[2,3];

int[] flatArray = parts.ToArray();
// Copying the array with the same dimensions can easily be put into an extension 
// method if you need it, nothing to grab a library for ...
```

## Easy iteration

```
int[,] parts = new int[2,3];

foreach(var item in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

## Slicing of arrays

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 2,3,4,5,6 };
int[] slice = arr.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();

// Multidimensional slice 
int[,] parts = new int[2,3];
int[] slice = arr.Cast<int>().Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();
```

The awkward `.Cast<int>` in the last example is [due to the quirk that multidimensional arrays in C# are only `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-does-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet).

Comment: LINQ is lacking numerical features, only works well with 1 dimension and it'll be significantly slower than a good numerics lib.

Comment: Well, the question is about array manipulation, it doesn't say whether performance or numerical computation is a factor.

Comment: At least "array slicing" and "n dimensions" were mentioned and are lacking in LINQ.

Comment: An array slice points into the original array. You're producing copies of the slice.

Comment: @driis of course you need a library! Things like matrix addition, subtraction, dot products, cross products and determinants need not be implemented from scratch!

Answer (score 8):

NumPY has been ported to .NET via IronPython.

Comment: This link points to the original PTVS project. PTVS never (really) implemented numpy and is outdated now. The only project which gets close to numpy on .NET is [ILNumerics](https://ilnumerics.net)

Comment: alternative lib 1: https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET

Comment: alternative lib 2: https://github.com/Quansight-Labs/numpy.net

Comment: alternative lib 3: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/