# Convert object[,] to string[,]?

Tags: c#

How would you convert `object[,]` to `string[,]` ?

```
Object[,] myObjects= // sth
string[,] myString = // ?!? Array.ConvertAll(myObjects, s => (string)s) // this doesn't work
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT : Of course, a loop solution will obviously do it, however I was envisioning a more elegant solution both in terms of code and in performance.

EDIT2 : The `object[,]` contains of course `string`s (and digits, but this doesn't matter for now).

Comment: Are you actually trying to convert to `string[,]` or `string[]`? Your question is inconsistent.

Comment: I assume two nested loops are out of the question?

Comment: Why can't you just use some loops

Comment: When you say convert, do you mean call `ToString()` or should the code fail if the `object`s are not `string`s?

Comment: can anyone please tell me what [,] is, i mean, i haven't seen it before, but the compiler accepts it. any reference is welcome.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee a multidimensional array.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: It looks like you assume all the entries are already strings, since you simply say `(string)s` in the commented-out part. If it is possible that `myObjects` really has the runtime-type of a `string[,]`, start by checking that: `var myStrings = myObjects as string[,]; if (myStrings == null) { /* do as suggested in the answers instead */ }`

Comment: some details on why multidimensional arrays suck http://stackoverflow.com/q/275073/659190, I'd be tempted to convert to `IList<IList<>>`.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays are not collections, nothing can be done except for looping (or converting throuhg black magic). If the `Object[,]` actually contains strings, why isn't it a `string[,]` in the first place ?

Comment: Note that every kind of LINQ queries / extension methods (and similar) are just a **beautiful** way to DO RAW **FOR** LOOPS. You'll probably get NO performance improvement at all.

Comment: @Jodrell : They are all strings, or at least convertible to strings.

Comment: @Alex  : 10x. So, looping is the only solution ? It contains `object[,]` and not `string[,]`, because it comes from a generic table, which may contains stuff other than `string`s, but in my case I know for sure they are only `string`s, and I want to post process them.

Answer (score 4):

```
Object[,] myObjects = new Object[3, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 },
                                        { 5, 6 } };

string[,] myString = new string[3, 2];

for (int i = myObjects.GetLowerBound(0); i < myObjects.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
     for (int j = myObjects.GetLowerBound(1); j < myObjects.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
     {
          myString[i, j] = myObjects[i, j].ToString();
     }
}

foreach (var item in myString)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.GetType(), item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
System.String - 1
System.String - 2
System.String - 3
System.String - 4
System.String - 5
System.String - 6
```

Comment: [What if the array's lower bounds are not 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx)?

Comment: @Soner Gönül : 10x, however I was envisioning a more elegant solution in terms of code and performance. This will obviously do. as well.

Comment: @HeinrichStack I research this type of conversion for multidiamentionals array but I coulnd't find any better way to do this.

Comment: @ta.speot.is from the [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx) article:
>Generally, the .NET Framework class library and many programming languages do not handle nonzero lower bounds.

Comment: @Johnbot I merely asked the question, "what if the array's lower bounds are not 0".

Answer (score 4):

You can allocate space like this

```
string[,] myString = new string[myObjects.GetLength(0),myObjects.GetLength(1)];
```

Then some loops should work fine, like this:

```
for(int k=0;k < myObjects.GetLength(0);k++)
    for(int l=0;l < myObjects.GetLength(1);l++)
        myString[k,l] = myObjects[k,l].ToString();
```

Comment: @HeinrichStack, This is good, assuming `ToString` provides the conversion you require. For many classes that do not override `ToString()` the type name in braces is less than useful. However, you can't expect "useful" to be automatically defined for you, its context sensitive.

Comment: you don't instantiate `myString`

Comment: @Jodrell - I didn't assign values to myObjects too, I'm assuming there is other code, this is just a snippet, but you have a point.

Comment: @Hogan 10x, however I was envisioning a more elegant solution in terms of code and performance. This will obviously do. as well.

Comment: [What if the array's lower bounds are not 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx)?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Then it would be slightly more complicated -- the allocation and the loop would need to account for it.

Answer (score 4):

Given the other answers, it's really easy to write your own `ConvertAll` method for 2D arrays:

```
public static TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] array, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    var result = new TOutput[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); ++j)
            result[i, j] = converter(array[i, j]);

    return result;
}
```

Just because the authors of .NET didn't care to include this method, there's no need to give up entirely. It's pretty straight forward to write it yourself.

(You could make it an extension method if you wanted.)

**EDIT after comments:** If you really want to handle arrays whose lower bound (in some dimension) is not zero, it goes like this:

```
public static TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] array, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    int xMin = array.GetLowerBound(0);
    int xLen = array.GetLength(0);
    int yMin = array.GetLowerBound(1);
    int yLen = array.GetLength(1);
    var result = (TOutput[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TOutput), new[] { xLen, yLen, }, new[] { xMin, yMin, });
    for (int x = xMin; x < xMin + xLen; ++x)
        for (int y = yMin; y < yMin + yLen; ++y)
            result[x, y] = converter(array[x, y]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is I implicitly assumed that the 2D array was created with usual C# syntax. Of course I know it is possible to create an array like this: `(object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 10, 20, }, new[] { -3, -7, });`, but who does that? This question was tagged C#, you know. Should I include code to handle this unlikely case?

Comment: *This question was tagged C#, you know* What language is `(object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 10, 20, }, new[] { -3, -7, });` written in?

Comment: @ta.speot.is provide a better solution

Comment: @WiiMaxx [I'd just be re-posting this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16297879/242520).

Comment: @ta.speot.is Alright, I included the case with non-zero lower bounds. Not that I think ___any___ C# developer uses it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is so that's the best way to do it? i was hopping there would maybe an generic way to do this like this one

Comment: @WiiMaxx Just take the answer I linked to and generalise it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thank you. Bonus points for preserving the lower bound for the new array.

Comment: @ta.speot.is You really need only the first version, before my edit. I promise.

Answer (score 3):

This should be one of the simplest and the fastest way, assuming that every element in the `src` array can be cast down to the `dst` array type.

```
object[,] src = new object[,]
{
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"spam", "eggs"},
};

string[,] dest = new string[src.GetLength(0), src.GetLength(1)];
Array.Copy(src, dest, src.Length);
```

Comment: [This doesn't preserve the lower bound of the source array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx).

Comment: @ta.speot.is : Thas true, so possible trick will be to fill the rest with null, and copy to that area. Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Paolo Moretti : nice solution.

Comment: @WiiMaxx : what did you use, `double`s ?

Comment: @HeinrichStack i just changed `"eggs"` to `5`

Comment: @WiiMaxx In my opinion it doesn't make any sense create an object array containing multiple types (e.g `{"spam", 5, 1.0}`) and then pretending that some magic method can perform all the conversions we are expecting; :) especially if you consider that there are several of ways to convert a number to string, depending on the `CultureInfo` for example.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti i mentioned the digits only because of the 2Edit from the OP _"(and digits, but this doesn't matter for now)."_ .So no worries i'm fine with your solution

Comment: @WiiMaxx : Indeed, the `Array.Copy` method crashes with digits. I will need time to understand, why this is happening and how to be avoided. I thought digits will be treated easily some how, once it is done with strings. Moreover, I tried object[] with only digits. The same problem with the Copy method.

Comment: @Paolo Moretti : the sense with the array with multiple types come e.g. when working with Excel Tables, than you would have these multiple types in it.

Comment: @HeinrichStack It crashes because `Array.Copy` is performing a cast for every element and casting a number to string raise an `InvalidCastException`. Try this code, for example: `object n = 1; string s = (string)n;`

Comment: @HeinrichStack maybe you should  test Jeppe Stig Nielsen [EDIT version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16298512/1993545) i don't know how but it works :D

Comment: @WiiMaxx : I was having a similar solution before posting the question.

Comment: @Paolo Moretti : I didn't quite get your answer? What will be the exact calling of the Array.CopyMethod ?