# Jagged array T[][] to IEnumerable<T[]>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to understand why implicit conversion in the following code causes `StackOverflowException`. I think it is a covariance/contravariance issue, but I cannot explain why at the moment.

Crashes NUnit:

```
private List<T[]> _NodesContent = new List<T[]>();
private UnrolledLinkedListBuilder<T> AddNodes(IEnumerable<T[]> nodes)
{
    _NodesContent.AddRange(nodes);
    return this;
}

public UnrolledLinkedListBuilder<T> AddNodes(params T[][] nodes)
{
    return AddNodes(nodes);
}
```

Works:

```
private List<T[]> _NodesContent = new List<T[]>();
private UnrolledLinkedListBuilder<T> AddNodes(IEnumerable<T[]> nodes)
{
    _NodesContent.AddRange(nodes);
    return this;
}

public UnrolledLinkedListBuilder<T> AddNodes(params T[][] nodes)
{
    return AddNodes((IEnumerable<T[])nodes);
}
```

As I understand from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/275107/761755 conversion should be performed implicitly.
Moreover, if in the first example you directly call `_NodesContent.AddRange(nodes)` from `AddNodes(T[][])` there will be no exception.

Comment: Because when you call `AddNodes` passing `T[][]` - best fitting overload is of course one that accepts `T[][]`, not one that accepts `IEnumerable<T[]>`. It doesn't matter if it's possible to convert `T[][]` to `IEnumerable<T[]>` or not.

Comment: Why you expect that you don't get a `StackOverflowException`? You are passing the argument directly to the method in which you are. It would be a compiler bug if you would call a different method (overload) then.

Comment: "As I understand conversion should be performed implicitly." Sure, but a conversion will only happen **if a conversion is necessary.** But a conversion is not necessary. `nodes` is a `T[][]`. There is a method overload that takes a `T[][]` as parameter, so that one will be chosen, resulting in a stack overflow.

Comment: @Evk Thanks a lot. Now I see my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand why implicit conversion in the following code
>   causes StackOverflowException.

Well, there is no implicit conversion necessary. But isn't it obvious? Your first method calls itself because you pass the argument as it is:

```
public UnrolledLinkedListBuilder<T> AddNodes(params T[][] nodes)
{
    return AddNodes(nodes);
}
```

It was a compiler bug if that would not cause a `StackOverflowException` in any case:

```
public SomeReturnType AnyMethod(AnyType x)
{
    return AnyMethod(x); // StackOverflowException
}
```

It doesn't matter that the parameter is using `params` because it's not possible to have another method with the same parameter type without `params` because that was ambiguous. So this will always be the best candidate.

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now.

Comment: *It was a compiler bug if that would not cause a `StackOverflowException` in any case* Are you saying that compiler do not allowed to do tail call optimization here?

Comment: @PetSerAl: no, i just meant that it's not possible that a different method-overload is called from within a method when you pass the argument as it is(without casting). Otherwise the question arises why this method was called in the first place.